# concat all the members of a class

Tags: c#

I am hard coding something that I am sure can be done more cleverly -- fun little problem -- using c# 6.0

How can I reduce this - it goes on another 20 lines.

```
  string fullLine = newLine.col1_index_no +
            newLine.col2_depot_custRef +
            newLine.col3_depot_no +
            newLine.col4_driver_id +
            newLine.col5_vehicle_id +
            newLine.col6_trans_type;
```

if it helps here is the class:

```
class lineBuilder
{
    public string col1_index_no { get; set; }
    public string col2_depot_custRef { get; set; }
    public string col3_depot_no { get; set; }
    public string col4_driver_id { get; set; }
    public string col5_vehicle_id { get; set; }
    public string col6_trans_type { get; set; }
    public string col7_sign_id { get; set; }
    public string col8_note_id { get; set; }
    public string col9_route_code { get; set; }
    public string col10_RA_no { get; set; }
    public string col11_doc_type { get; set; }
    public string col12_user_gen_flag { get; set; }
    public string col13_seq_no { get; set; }
    public string col14_pallet_id { get; set; }
    public string col15_tote_id { get; set; }
    public string col16_adj_type { get; set; }
    public string col17_rtn_sig_not_avlb { get; set; }
    public string col18_scan_dateTime { get; set; }
    public string col19_scan_in_time { get; set; }
    public string col20_AX_status { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: you can use reflection and traverse the properties to get their values and create the string. trick would be on getting the order you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via reflection. This sample code will print out all of the properties in alphabetical order:

```
var lb = new lineBuilder
{
    col1_index_no = "item one",
    col2_depot_custRef = "item depot custRef"
    col10_RA_no = "further values will not make this explanation any clearer"
};

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(lineBuilder)
                                            .GetProperties()
                                            .Where(p => p.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)))
                                            .OrderBy(p => p.Name);

foreach(PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
{
    var value = (string)propertyInfo.GetValue(lb);  
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", propertyInfo.Name, value ?? String.Empty));
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

However, you don't want them in alphabetical order, you want them in numeric order.

You need a different `OrderBy` clause.

If all of your property names follow the format `col{number}`, you can use a regular expression to extract the number from each name and use that to perform your ordering.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^col(\d+)");

IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(lineBuilder)
                                            .GetProperties()
                                    .Where(p => p.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)))
                                    .OrderBy(p => int.Parse(regex.Match(p.Name).Groups[1].Value));
```

Comment: I knew it would have something to do with reflection, I just could not get my head around it.  Thanks for adding to my bag of tricks, I will play around with this Andrew...I always forget about Regex formatting....